# How to block Bad robots, spiders, crawlers and harvesters

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, monitoring, fail2ban, logging

I'm sick and tired of this bad robots, spiders, crawlers and harvesters. I have already configured my server to block IP connected for 5 minutes and with maxretry of 250 using fail2ban. But still some of them cannot be intercept with 250 maxretry as they are not accessing it more than 250 within 5 minutes.

Here's my jail.local config:

```
[http-get-dos]
enabled = true
filter = http-get-dos
logpath = /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log
maxretry = 250
findtime = 300
#ban for 10 hours
bantime = 36000
action = iptables-multiport[name=HTTP, port="http,https", protocol=tcp]
         cloudflare-blacklist
         sendmail-whois[name=HTTP, dest=webmaster@mysite.com]
```

Here's the http-get-dos.conf filter file:

```
[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST)

ignoreregex =
```

The majority of the tutorial that can block this crawler is using apache. But because I am using nginx, I cannot use them. Here's one [tutorial](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/block-bad-bots.html) I found.

Here's the example log of this robot:

```
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:19 +0800] "GET /php?page=9 HTTP/1.1" 200 10897 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=8" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:22 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/jkev/jkev_search.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 35199 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/jkev/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:24 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/images/kalola/sk_3.jpg?itok=-pXuOEq2 HTTP/1.1" 200 3958 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:24 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/images/kalola/sk_1.jpg?itok=ug6jsTPP HTTP/1.1" 200 3958 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:24 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/images/kalola/sk_2.jpg?itok=ZPOMnJeK HTTP/1.1" 200 3958 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:26 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/images/argie/currency.jpg?itok=hodqOr4_ HTTP/1.1" 200 7976 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:26 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/images/localhost27/untitled.jpg?itok=uVeczDjI HTTP/1.1" 200 3136 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:26 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/images/Oelasor/screenshot_11.jpg?itok=uu3d0GpX HTTP/1.1" 200 6674 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:27 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/images/localhost27/member.jpg?itok=inA9ULoC HTTP/1.1" 200 4500 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:28 +0800] "GET /php/4852/shopping-cart-checkout-using-codeigniter.html HTTP/1.1" 200 11414 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:29 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/images/admin/codeigniter_shopping_cart.jpg?itok=QO0YV6JP HTTP/1.1" 200 22534 "http://www.mysite.com/php/4852/shopping-cart-checkout-using-codeigniter.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:32 +0800] "GET /php/4846/simple-ajax-example-php.html HTTP/1.1" 200 10174 "http://www.mysite.com/php?page=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:34 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/teejaygenius/e_library.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 3655400 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/teejaygenius/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:36 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/Chritian/bus.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 4462491 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/Chritian/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:00:00:37 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/images/kalola/sk_2.jpg?itok=1N0a__bq HTTP/1.1" 200 9693 "http://www.mysite.com/php/4846/simple-ajax-example-php.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"e220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:03:13 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 1555432 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"                                                                                                                             220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:03:20 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18541381 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:03:29 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 6186320 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:03:31 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 13495467 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:03:34 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 17908605 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:03:51 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 10082448 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:03:57 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 8639709 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:03 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 12150765 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:04 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 17972316 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:09 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18453052 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:23 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 777716 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:40 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 8033075 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:45 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 12935983 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:49 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 8262600 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:49 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 11598966 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:49 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 11249310 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:04:57 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 5969210 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:02 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 12978641 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:03 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 13390784 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:07 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 6124786 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:15 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 9962834 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:19 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 12021359 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:27 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 8432875 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:44 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18371964 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:46 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 19867749 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:05:50 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18164900 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:00 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 17839100 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:01 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18329973 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:11 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18651902 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:31 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 9858200 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:34 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 12914955 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:36 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 13315966 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:38 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 12804285 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:41 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 6043976 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:42 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 11900897 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:06:52 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 8293782 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:07:06 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 11582412 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:07:24 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18667357 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:07:27 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 7977266 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:07:35 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 11190040 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:07:36 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18555860 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:09 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 5932064 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:10 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 12730175 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:13 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 13208853 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:16 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 8178860 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:22 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 5896753 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:25 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 8183834 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:26 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 12671818 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:30 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18581925 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:36 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18224268 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:37 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 11761743 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:51 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 11412627 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:08:59 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 18600749 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:09:01 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/system1.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 11129155 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/mindgamez/" "FDM 3.x"
220.225.127.41 - - [24/Jul/2013:03:09:14 +0800] "GET /sites/default/files/download/argie/tameraplazainn.zip HTTP/1.1" 206 7836467 "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/download/argie/" "FDM 3.x"
```

Here's the frequency of visits by hour:

```
# grep "220.225.127.41" /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c
545 00:00
524 01:00
404 02:00
491 03:00
396 04:00
183 05:00
```

Here's the frequency of visits by minute (around 12 midnight):

```
# grep "220.225.127.41 - - \[24/Jul/2013:00" /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 > 10) print $0}'
33 00:00
14 00:01
12 00:03
26 00:05
15 00:10
18 00:11
22 00:13
15 00:14
14 00:15
15 00:18
21 00:19
17 00:20
15 00:23
14 00:24
17 00:25
27 00:29
15 00:30
18 00:32
14 00:52
```

Here's the frequency of visits by minute (around 1AM):

```
# grep "220.225.127.41 - - \[24/Jul/2013:01" /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 > 10) print $0}'
16 01:01
16 01:02
12 01:05
16 01:06
14 01:10
14 01:11
14 01:12
13 01:14
22 01:16
18 01:17
13 01:21
21 01:22
14 01:26
20 01:37
30 01:38
13 01:45
11 01:50
17 01:51
11 01:53
```

Is there a way to block this using IPTables or something?

If I will lower it, I'm afraid some of the legitimate traffic will be ban also.

The access rate is very low. I cannot set the maxretry to something like 50 or even 70. That will also ban legitimate traffic.

So how can I prevent this one? They consume too much bandwidth. Before my normal bandwidth is at 59.31 GB per day but now it reaches up to 136.74 GB.

Comment: Check their user-agents. If they are using a specific spider-related user agent, it should be simple enough to block based on that.

Comment: hi mark, can you give me some little guidance on where to check this? is it using fail2ban? or robots.txt? I believe robots.txt is of no use here since they can ignore it easily.

Comment: According to your log, the user-agent is `FDM 3.x` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599544/how-to-block-specific-human-looking-user-agent-in-nginx for info on how to block.

Comment: Also, a quick google shows this probably isn't a normal spider, but rather someone specifically scraping your entire site for content: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Download_Manager

Comment: You may also want to set up a honeypot...  Just add an invisible link on the home page that triggers your ban if loaded.  Humans will not (normally) access it as it's not visible but crawlers will.

Comment: @ChrisNava I am currently researching about honeypot. I've already spent several hours on how I can block this robots using honeypot. Do you know of any link that will guide me?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been in a position to do this in a long time... This link looks like it will help you though. It mentions fail2ban integration of a "bottrap"  http://www.bsdguides.org/2012/a-simple-bot-trap-using-robots-txt/  I would add an invisible link on any page you want to protect in addition to the robots.txt suggestion.

Comment: @MarkHenderson. User-agent is not the way to go, they can be faked very easily. The ones that don't fake are more than likely the bots you do want indexing your site

Comment: @geosword if you have a better idea feel free to post an answer. My comment after all is just that - a comment.

Comment: Whit nginx you can use limit_req, and for iptables use dos-deflate or maybe csf - ldf whit webmin.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, as a first step, limiting the number of connections could help (IPTABLES):

(from http://www.extrapepperoni.com/post/2013/03/iptables%3A-connlimit):

```
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport    80 -s xxx.yyy.0.0/16 --syn -m connlimit ! --connlimit-above 20
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport    80                   --syn -m connlimit ! --connlimit-above 5 --connlimit-mask 24
```

This will mostly help against DDoS attacks, but might be part of your problem:
The first rule allows internal users (from a specific network) to connect with up to 20 connections.
The second rule allows everybody else to only connect with 5 connections at a time.

A more general but quite complex command line tool for traffic shaping is tc:
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/

With tc you can limit the bandwidth of a particular user, service or client.